# Target Framework for ClickOnce Deployment

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, clickonce, prerequisites

We have an Excel-Addin Project which is published with ClickOnce Deployment.
We want to target .NET Framework Version 4.5.x and therefore need this as a prerequisite during install process. When we target 4.5 in the publish settings, it will require me to install exact 4.5 even if 4.5.1 or 4.5.2 is installed. This also applies if we target only version 4.5.1: 4.5 or 4.5.2 being already installed wont match.

I also tried to select all together 4.5/4.5.1/4.5.2 as prerequisites but then all 3 versions need to be installed.

How can I target 4.5.x as runtime target in the ClickOnce prerequisite?

Thanks for helping